# How can I use create a program that uses GDI+ 1.0 on XP and 1.1 on Vista/Win7

Tags: visual-c++, gdi+

I know that if I use the features of GDI+ 1.1, the .EXE file won't run on Windows XP.
I want to make a program that runs on Windows XP and Windows 7 both, and use the GDI+ 1.1 feature on Win7.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you create a DLL that uses 1.0 and another that uses 1.1, and choose which to load at runtime based on the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to put your GDI+ 1.1 code in `#ifdef`s and compile it to two different DLLs -- one with the code and one without. Then at runtime load the DLL that will work. Maybe you could even attempt to load the 1.1 DLL and if that fails fall back to the 1.0 DLL.